# Where is the valid 'assembly' attribute Location?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to use :
ZXing.Net.Mobile for Forms on My Xamarin.Forms app 
https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile.forms

```
namespace MnakabAlshabaViewBook.Droid
{
    [Activity ( Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    [assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.Flashlight)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

            ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();

            LoadApplication(new App());

        }
```

I get the following error:

> 'assembly' is not a valid attribute location for this
>   declarations.Valid attribute locations for this declaration are
>   'type'. all attributes in this block will be ignored .

where i should put : 
`[assembly: UsesPermission (Android.Manifest.Permission.Flashlight)]` ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put the assembly attribute above the namespace, so rearrange it like this:

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.Flashlight)]
namespace MnakabAlshabaViewBook.Droid
{
    [Activity ( Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
       //... Rest of code is here ...
```